# Temporary moving of Cooling Towers from roof

Tags: hvac, cooling

I am working on the replacement of 2 air cooled cooling towers at a hospital. the cooling towers are located on the roof, whilst the water-cooled chillers are located in a plantroom in the basement. Currently, there is another project going on which requires the slab of the hospital to be worked on. This means the cooling towers, which supply cooling to the entire hospital, needs to be moved. Is there anyone who has experienced a similar situation and knows solutions to keep the cooling for the hospital whilst having the cooling towers removed from the roof? Considering the cooling towers are looking to be replaced, returning them to the roof is not a concern.

Comment: So connect to another method of cooling away from where the work is being carried out - dust etc. How much cooling is needed? what is the current capacity?

Comment: Obviously you'll have to construct new permanent or temporary cooling towers off the roof and you will need downtime to pipe them in.  I've never done this but the concept is simple.  Making it happen is of course quite the job.